# SharePoint 2013 custom design for each team site?

Tags: site, design, team

Our intranet has 3 departments, each department has a team site.. I am in control of one of the departments and I want to have a different design than the others. Is it possible to do it without creating a master page that affects the other departments?

If so, where could I find the information on how to do it? I have been banging my head against the screen for the last week.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: How is the structure of the sites? Are they three different site collections? Are they three different subsites within a common root site?

Answer (score 2):

Each site can have it's own master page. If you're opting for minimal branding changes such as color, font and theme etc, it's possible to achieve such using Alternate CSS for that site. However, you're making structural changes (moving elements) then create a new master page and apply it the particular site or site collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a different master page for each team site the only thing you need to do is activate the SharePoint publishing features for each team site.
Then go to Site Settings -> Master Page under Look and Feel and select the new master.